# How do I put shapes (transform) over each other with ::before and ::after in CSS? Edge wont display shape over background

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, css-transforms, css-shapes

I created two slanted shapes to be displayed on top of a container with background image. I used `::before` and `::after` to get the shapes over the same image.

It works in Firefox and Chrome but not in edge.

What am I missing?

This is what I want and what happens in Chrome:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bny60o505cz2f2k/screen1.png

This is what happens in Edge:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ix6v8gyxq0y6eo4/screen2.png

The blue shape has `::before`, but `::before` is not displayed in Edge. (when I give the blue shape the pseudo element `::before` it is displayed but then the white shape is not possible.

```css
.titelsectie {
    z-index:0!important;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/2404370/pexels-photo-2404370.jpeg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0!important;
    padding-top: 100px!important;
}
.titelsectie::after{
    content: " ";
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    left: -8%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0!important;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform: skew(-16deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-16deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(-16deg, 0deg);
}
.titelsectie::before {
    content: " ";
    background-color: #201547;
    position: absolute!important;
    width: 10%;
    height: 85%;
    left: -8%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999!important;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform: skew(-16deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-16deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(-16deg, 0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="titelsectie">
  <div class="fusion-builder-row fusion-row ">
    <div class="fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion_builder_column_1_2 fusion-builder-column-1 fusion-one-half fusion-column-first 1_2" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:20px;width:48%; margin-right: 4%;">
      <div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;background-position:left top;background-repeat:no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;" data-bg-url=""> 
    <!-- some content with text, buttons and titles--> 

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi; please include the HTML that this CSS applies to - the question needs to have an [mcve] in order to help (links and images don't count).

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the code (did strip out the content)

Comment: I tested your code on my side and there's no difference in Edge and in Chrome. You can see the result -> in Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1ll3.png, in Edge: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0AOs.png. What version of Edge are you using? My Edge version is 44.18362.1.0. If you're using the older version of Edge, you can move to the latest version and try again.

Comment: thanks for your response. I solved it (see my answer). I did update the snippet te have a background image, so others can use it if they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Thanks for your responses. I also noticed that the stripped down code worked on my side. Therefore the code must be correct.

So I decided to use the inspect tool in edge.

I'm building my site in WordPress with the theme AVADA. I found out that avada added some CSS just for IE / Edge. on the before element for the full width part. And that CSS was overwriting all the important bits. (.fusion-fullwidth.fusion-ie-mode::before)

I added !important to all those bits and all is fine now! (can't believe I spend big part of yesterday afternoon trying to solve this ;-) )